# Problemas al instalar php 5.5.9 en ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

Buenas tardes colegas, el dia de hoy intentaba subir la version de php 5.5.9 a 7.1 y se hizo de manera exitosa, lo malo fue que me dio errores en algunos sistemas de la empresa puesto que son antiguos y trabajan con php 5.5, ahora intento regresar a la version anterior y me arroja el siguiente error en la consola...

```
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 php-rrd : Depende: librrd4 (>= 1.4~rc2) pero no es instalable
 php-ssh2 : Depende: libssh2-1 (>= 1.2.9) pero no es instalable
 php-yac : Entra en conflicto: php-xcache pero 3.2.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 va a ser instalado
 php-yaml : Depende: libyaml-0-2 pero no es instalable
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

para eliminar de nuevo php y volver a instalarlo utilice: `sudo apt-get -y purge php.*`
ya he probado a remover paquetes rotos con los comandos 
`sudo apt-get autoremove` y `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Espero poder haberme dado a entender y a la ves encontrar la solucion.... de antemano gracias

Comment: Estás seguro de que tiene que ser PHP 5.5.9? Pregunto porque de verdad va a ser muy difícil encontrar un PPA con PHP 5.5 con sus bugs y hoyos de seguridad. Lo mínimo que está publicado es PHP 5.6.10.

Comment: Si bro, de hecho existen varios sistemas con versiones incluso anteriores y pues por esa razon intente subir la version de php pero la mayoria de los sistemas no funcionaron puesto que las funciones que utiilzan estan obsoletas y php7 las elimino, lo mas que corren es php5.5.9

Comment: Yo veo muy difícil que no corran con PHP 5.6, si son muy pocos los breaking changes vs PHP 5.4. De memoria no me acuerdo de ninguno que sea realmente breaking change

Comment: Si, de hecho hay aplicaciones con php inferiores a la 5, probe a instalar la 5.6 pero aun siguen habiendo aplicaciones que no funcionan

Comment: Inferiores a la 5... :(  :o  eso sí está preocupante

Comment: Creo (en mi humilde opinión) que deberían, tu y la empresa, optar de actualizar el código. Pros: más estable, más rápido, más seguro etc... Contra: el tiempo para actualizar el código

Comment: Si @aldanux, de hecho empezaremos con eso, ya hablamos a los dueños que adquirieron los sistemas hace tiempo y empezaremos por rehacer los  sistemas con php 7 y laravel, solo que para poder proceder al menos debemos hacer que los sistemas se ejecuten

Comment: @EliobethRuizHernandez yo te aconsejaría reescribir el código para que funcione con 5.6 y luego , por detrás mientras tengáis ese corriendo , ir trabajando en rehacerlo en php7 y con laravel. Tener un proyecto parado , cuando tiene que correr es pérdida de tiempo y dinero , por consiguiente la prioridad tiene que ser meter en producción lo antes posible con una versión minimamente estable como la 5.6 y luego pasar a "renovarla".